# how to save an image in mysql db via json array?

Tags: android, json, image

i've been trying to save an image coming from an android application into a php server db. 
here is my code..

android:

```
public class TestCaseActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv;
String text;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    text    = "";

    try {
        postData();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void postData() throws JSONException{  
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://uknwhu.site40.net/blitz/mydata2.php");
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

    byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    String ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

    try {
        // JSON data:
        json.put("name", "jmaraz");
        json.put("position", "SE");
        json.put("photo", ba1);

        JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
        postjson.put(json);

        // Post the data:
        httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
        httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        System.out.print(json);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        // for JSON:
        if(response != null)
        {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) response.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            text = sb.toString();
        }

        tv.setText(text);

    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

}

here is my php code:

```
<?php 
include_once("connection.php");
$json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];

$data = json_decode($json);
//header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
// all are texts 
$name = $data->name;
$pos = $data->position;
$imageString = $data->photo;
$phoneNo = "123456789"; // for testing
// decoding the string 
$realImage = base64_decode($imageString);

//$description = 
//$latitude = 
//$longitude = 


$path = "images/".$phoneNo.".jpg";
$handle = fopen($path, 'wb');
$numbytes = fwrite($handle, $realImage);
fclose($handle);

$imageName = $path; 

// trimming and removing spaces for identifier
$identifier = trim($name);
$identifier = str_replace(" ","",$identifier);

// inserting into database
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM details WHERE identifier ='$identifier'");
$row = mysql_num_rows($query1);

if($row >0){
echo "Similar record found! Please change the name and try agin";

}else{
//$query2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO details (phoneNo, identifier, name,description,latitude,longitude,imageName)


$query2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO details (phoneNo, identifier, name,imageName)
VALUES('".$phoneNo."', '".$identifier."','".$name."','".$imageName."')");
echo "Done...!";
}

?>
```

but i get the "Bad Request" message when running the android application. It works fine for texts. How to save the image? Could anybody please help me?

Thanks...

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, but your code has glaring SQL injection vulnerabilities. You should either use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on the strings, or better yet, use PDO with Parameterized Queries (concatenating your own SQL is a horrible idea!).

Comment: You are also doing http request in the main thread. Plz read: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: thx for the advice.. im still testing on this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use below code

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
     HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("serverurl");
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", name));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RecipientMobileNumber", recepnumber));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SenderMobileNumber", sendernumber));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MessageBody", msg));         
     MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    for(int index=0; index < pairs.size(); index++) {
    if(pairs.get(index).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("upload")) {
      ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(new File pairs.get(index).getValue()), "application/octet-stream");
          entity.addPart(pairs.get(index).getName(), cbFile);                    
     } else {                    
               entity.addPart(pairs.get(index).getName(), new StringBody(pairs.get(index).getValue()));
     }
     }
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
```

Comment: Server side try to read the image data as how you read the file upload

Comment: i need to send texts, coordinates and images altogether. how can i do it with above method?

Comment: tx..but i get errors when declaring "MultipartEntity". do you know how to do this via json? Because im suppose to do this using a json array...

Comment: why was this accepted as the answer without using json? I came here because it was suppose to be helpful for json arrays - misleading!